# Proper / fastest way to compare two big sets of data in database

Tags: sql, database, compare

I want to compare 2 big sets of data (2 tables), each containing approximately 10,000,000 records: `id` and hash of other attributes.

If `id` on the left and right side is the same, but hash is different, I need to compare every attribute to see which one has changed.
What is the best way to achieve that?

I've tried [DiffKit](http://www.diffkit.org/) and I'm looking for something maybe faster.

Comment: If you're using SQL Server, you will probably get the best performance by writing a SQL Server Integration Services (SSIS) package.

Comment: I haven't looked very far into it, but if `DiffKit` is performing its checks in-db, (ie, it just auto-writes the statements), you're unlikely to do much better in the common case.  You could maybe write a statement yourself; what have you tried yourself?  It would also help to know more about your RDBMS, tables, and dataset (like, how many repetitions of `id`).

Comment: When you say each table contains "hash of other attributes", do you mean that this value is stored as a column? Is the combination (id, hash) indexed in at least one of the tables?

Comment: Yes, it is stored as a separate column. There are indexes on ID column in both of the tables but I can another index.

Answer (score 0):

The following query will have a row for every `id` where the hash differs and only contains the columns that are different (everything else is NULL)

```
SELECT a.id
    , NULLIF(a.col1,b.col1) t1_col1
    , NULLIF(b.col1,a.col1) t2_col1
    , NULLIF(a.col2,b.col2) t1_col2
    , NULLIF(b.col2,a.col2) t2_col2
    […]
FROM table1 a INNER JOIN table2 b
ON a.id = b.id
AND a.hash <> b.hash
```

An index on (id,hash) will speed the query up a bit.

Comment: Thanks, I'll see how fast can it get :)

Comment: This kind of does the trick, but one of the columns is an reference to another table... I have to  work it out somehow. Big thanks!